# How Can i use Gridview instead of textbox

Tags: gridview, textbox

Haw can i use a grideview as a textbox?
Actually I want have a textbox in my project to show a value from database But I want User click on a + button to add textbox and add information
I khow I should do it with gridview But I dont know how really?
i work Base on ASP.NET and C#

Answer (score 0):

You probably should look into adding rows to the GridView as the user clicks the button. Your initial GridView should have a column with a TextBox.

Here's an example you can follow:
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Adding-Dynamic-Rows-in-ASP.Net-GridView-Control-with-TextBoxes.aspx

Comment: Links are great references, but it helps if you can include a sample of the relevant code from the resource as links can break over time. Welcome to Stack Overflow.